# Share appstore url with other apps

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, share

Is there any way to share web url (specifically link to an app in appstore) using `UIDocumentInteractionController`?

If that is not feasible what are the other options to enable the user to share the appstore url with other apps? (I am aware of [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit))

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use App Groups. 
Create the same app group in both apps, and share with nsuserdefaults like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.name"];
```